# PHP webpages in sub-directory cannot be accessed

Tags: htaccess, php, apache, http-code-500

I've got a university club website at `thing.uni.ac.uk/meow/foobar` which also has the domain `foobar.co.uk`. I don't have access to the config. I set up this website using HTML/CSS/JS alone and it's been fine, but now I've started learning PHP and I'm trying to switch to `.php` pages instead of `.html` pages.

When debugging the problem I'm about to describe, I made a `page.php` file and a `page.html` file that are identical (a simple hello world without any PHP tags). The problem I face is that if I try to go to `foobar.co.uk/alpha/example/page.php`, I get the following Internal Server Error:

> /www/htdocs/meow/foobar/alpha/example is not owned by group g_www_bar_meow_foobar or any other acceptable groups.

But if I go to `foobar.co.uk/alpha/example/page.html`, it works fine. If I try to go to the non-existent `foobar.co.uk/alpha/example/badger.php` it gives me the 404 page as I would expect. If I move `page.php` to `foobar.co.uk/alpha/page.php` then it works.

**Update**

I've checked the permissions of `page.php` that isn't in the offending directory compared to `page.php` that is, and both seem to have the same permissions:

[image]

---

I'm not sure this has anything to with the problem, but I have a htaccess file in the `foobar.co.uk/` directory which contains:

```
#redirect from the other domain to foobar.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?foobar\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://foobar.co.uk/$1 [R=302,L]

#remove trailing slash if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

(This is only the part which I think could be relevant) But this should only do rewrites for html files.

Comment: This *is not owned by group* tells me that it is a ownership or permissions thing. Php likely requires execute privs where html only requires read. If you have access to the directory, check the owner and group for the files you created and compare that to php pages that work okay.

Comment: As closetnoc says. I don't see how this can be related to .htaccess.

Comment: @closetnoc Sorry about the delay checking this. Anyway, the permissions seem to be the same for working php pages that aren't in this folder and broken identical copies that are in this folder. I've updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: @closetnoc I thought the same thing... shouldn't the permissions be set to `755`?

Answer (score -1):

What if you use php only as a container and include an html page in it? This would by the way be a good way to re-use html code.

For instance you have the contents in an html file called example.htm and in the php file you write:

`<?php`
`include('example.htm');`
`?>`

Comment: The point is nobody can access the page.php, regardless of its contents